# How to forbid calling a method C#

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, .net-security

I want to allow calling the method only from the particular methods. Take a look at the code below.

```
  private static void TargetMethod()
  {
  }

  private static void ForbiddenMethod()
  {
     TargetMethod();
  }

  private static void AllowedMethod()
  {
     TargetMethod();
  }
```

I need only AllowedMethod could call TargetMethod. How to do it using classes from `System.Security.Permissions`?

**Updated:** Thanks for your answers, but I don't want to debate about design of my application. I just want to know is it possible to do it using .net security or not?

Comment: If it's private, why does it matter?

Comment: How is this question voted up 9 times in just 6 minutes?

Comment: Are you trying to protect you from yourself? Other than that I can't imagine the use for this.

Comment: to Zakalwe
No, its just a habit.

Comment: @shoosh: And favourited twice?

Comment: @alga: It's extremely slow to do this, so if I were you, I would rethink this particular habit. At least for methods that are called frequently.

Comment: "I don't want to debate about design of application" - you came to the wrong place.

Comment: to Thorarin.
What is extremely slow? Access modifier? 
PS: the methods were called from method Main and I just copypasted it. Please don't pay attention to it and concentrate at the question.

Comment: Jeff Sternal, I perfectly know what the place it is. Moreover if you don't have an answer for the question maybe you had better be silent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAS cannot do this if the code is running in full trust.

If the code is executing in Full Trust (i.e. a normal, local application, not a silverlight application or something run from the network), then all .NET CAS checks are completely bypassed; any security attribute is simply ignored.

CAS simply walks the stack to determine permissions, though, and you can do that too, as Darin pointed out earlier by just checking the `StackTrace`.

Answer (score 24):

You can solve this using normal object-oriented design. Move `AllowedMethod` to a new class and make `ForbiddenMethod` a private method of that class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void AllowedMethod() { // ... }

    private void TargetMethod() { // ... }
}
```

AllowedMethod has access to private members, but no-one else have.

Answer (score 8):

I believe you should try to structure your code in meaningfull classes, and use the standard access modifiers (`private`, `protected`, `public`, `internal`). Is there any specific reason why this would not solve your problem?

The only alternative I can think of, would involve traversing the call stack from within the callee, but that would likely yield code mess and suboptimal performance.

Answer (score 7):

You could examine the call stack to accomplish this, but it is rather slow. I wouldn't recommend it if it can be avoided.

Should you still want to do this, you need to be careful to avoid method inlining as well, or your code might suddenly stop working under Release builds.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private static void TargetMethod()
{
    StackFrame fr = new StackFrame(1, false);
    Console.WriteLine(fr.GetMethod().Name);
}
```

As far as I know, there are no out-of-the-box attributes to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this is achievable with `System.Security.Permissions`, but inside `TargetMethod` you could get the caller and act accordingly:

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```

Comment: +1; and seems to be possible encapsulate that by implementing `CodeAccessPermission`

Comment: yeah, I know about it. But I'm interesting how to do it with security attributes.

Comment: This technique is slow and potentially fragile: Method inlining by the JITter could cause the `GetMethod` call to return unexpected results. (You can, of course, tell the JITter not to inline, as in Thorarin's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use CodeAccessPermission objects. You'd have to implement the interface in your own object to have it work like you're suggesting though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.codeaccesspermission.aspx

Answer (score 2):

By using Attributes  you can solve this issue.

Use Conditional Attributs.

In the top

```
#define "Show" 


  public void TargetMethod()
    {
      //Code
    }
   [ Conditional("Hidden")]
   public void HiddenMethod()
    {
       TargetMethod()
    }
 [ Conditional("Show")]
  public void AllowMethod()
    {
       TargetMethod()
    }
```

One of your methos will be called.

Comment: Well that removes `HiddenMethod` altogether. I think what alga wants, is to choose a select few methods that are allowed to call `TargetMethod` while denying *all others*, including ones in 3rd-party code, to call `TargetMethod`. Conditional compilation won't help achieve this ^^